# Get byteData from Cached Network Image Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using package [`CachedNetworkImage`](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) for network images. Is there any way we can get the bytedata of the displayed image of `CachedNetworkImage`? When I try and convert the image from network to byteData, it takes too long (almost 20 seconds for 7MB file) and since I am already showing image in it, I wonder if it is possible to get bytedata from imagechunk or something like that.

Comment: You can get cached image by a path on the device. On Android it could be in cache folder in the app directory.

Comment: Haven't tried the solution yet but found a solution to retrieve filePath of cache using `flutter_cache_manager`. Thank you :)